# How do you add 'org.eclipse.core:org.eclipse.core.runtime:3.7.0' library to Intellij ant build

Tags: java, ant, android-uiautomator, intellij-13

I can resolve the compile 'org.eclipse.core:org.eclipse.core.runtime:3.7.0' in gradle but instead using ant with the Intellij idea.  I've included the org.eclipse.core.runtime-3.7.0.jar in my libs folder.  I get the following errors.

Error:(22, 32) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class IProgressMonitor
  location: package org.eclipse.core.runtime

Error:(23, 32) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class IStatus
  location: package org.eclipse.core.runtime

Error:(24, 32) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Status
  location: package org.eclipse.core.runtime

I'm attempting to build Android's UIAutomatorView, if I put the code into Android Studio it seems to resolve IProgressMonitor, etc. with compile 'org.eclipse.core:org.eclipse.core.runtime:3.7.0' in gradle.

Here's a screenshot of my project structure and source error.

[image: my project structure and source error]

Is there an easy way to add this to ant or just convert the project to gradle (detailed steps please).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a build.xml file for your project. Look for the javac task (within the build file) that's being used to compile your code and make sure your jar is in the class path defined in there. If it's not, just copy it in.

Example taken from the below link:

```
<javac srcdir="${src}"
     destdir="${build}"
     includes="mypackage/p1/**,mypackage/p2/**"
     excludes="mypackage/p1/testpackage/**"
     classpath="YOUR_REQUIRED_JAR_FILE_HERE.jar"
     debug="on"
/>
```

Source: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html